# Charts JS xAxes is not shared by data

Tags: charts

I am visualizing multiple dataset on a Chart JS. Whenever I enable/disable a dataset. This dataset would create an instance of its data. On my case, it is xAxes.

[image]

and when I enable another dataset:
[image]

I want to disable creating another instance of xAxes and every it would share the same fixed axes.

```
    xAxes: [{
        type: 'time',
        distribution: 'linear',
        ticks: {
            source: 'data'
        },
        time: {
            parser: 'HH:mm:ss',
            unit: 'hour',
            unitStepSize: 1,
            //min: '00:00:00',
            //max: '23:59:59'
        }
    }],
```

**Update: 1**
I used `round: 'hour'`, to include in `xAxes.time`. It looks fixed. However, I don't know why points always go to corners and spread freely with time as shown:

[image]

**Update: 2**
I removed

```
/*ticks: {
                    source: 'data'
                },*/
```

Now it is scaled.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Removing the

```
        ticks: {
            source: 'data'
        },
```

made the graph scaled with time.